# Select and update data from database

Tags: vb.net

I have ID, FullName , Age, Sex as textbox and similar column in database.
Below is my code for search from database by ID.
But i don;t know how to update after search these data.

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub

    Private Sub Src_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Src.Click
        Form2.Show()
        Dim Connection As New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Satyam\Documents\Satyam.accdb;" & "Persist Security Info=False;" & "Jet OLEDB:Database Password=" & "your pass" & ";")

        Dim cmd As OleDbCommand
        Dim dr As OleDbDataReader
        Try
        Connection.Open()
        cmd = New OleDbCommand("SELECT *  from DailyWorkLoadRegister WHERE ID=" & txtID.Text & "", Connection)

        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
        If dr.Read Then
            Form2.txtID.Text = dr("ID")
            Form2.txtAge.Text = dr("Age")
            Form2.txtSex.Text = dr("Sex")
            Form2.txtFullName.Text = dr("FullName")

            dr.Close()
        Else
            MsgBox("No Record")
        End If
        Catch
        End Try
        Connection.Close()


    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Did my answer assist you?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to execute a non-query method which returns:

> For UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE statements, the return value is the
>   number of rows affected by the command. For all other types of
>   statements, the return value is -1. If a rollback occurs, the return
>   value is also -1.

Microsoft documentation -> [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.executenonquery%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Which is as simple as:

```
Dim ID : ID = Form2.txtID.Text
Dim Age : Age = Form2.txtAge.Text
Dim Sex : Sex = Form2.txtSex.Text
Dim FN : FN = Form2.txtFullName.Text


Dim command As New OleDbCommand("UPDATE YOUR_TABLE_NAME SET _
                                 FullName = '" & FN & "',_
                                 Age = '" & Age & "',_
                                 Sex = '" & Sex & "'_
                                 WHERE ID = '" & ID & "'", Connection)
command.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Comment: should i past this at buttonclick of form2?

Comment: That script should be activated after a user has updated the fields on Form2 and clicked submit.

Comment: It's a shame OleDb doesn't support parameterized queries, without a work-around*

Comment: I rewrite my code as below, but still an error occurred as
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException was unhandled
  ErrorCode=-2147217913
  Message="Data type mismatch in criteria expression."
  Source="Microsoft Office Access Database Engine"